# Nginx: Redirect all traffic to Coming Soon page except own IP

Tags: nginx, redirection

I have a folder called "coming-soon" that I would like to redirect all traffic to when the site is down for maintenance.

Currently, this is what I did:

----- START -----

location / {

allow 123.456.789;

deny all;

page_error 403 coming-soon/index.php;

}

location /coming-soon {

allow all;

}

----- END -----

The problem is, if someone tries to access a sub-folder (e.g. /blog), it will not redirect
to Coming Soon folder.

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the rest of your `server` configuration?

Answer (score 3):

```
location /coming-soon {
   #empty block
}
location / {
    if ($remote_addr != 123.456.789) {
       rewrite ^ /coming-soon/index.php last;
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553980/nginx-redirect-without-rewriting-the-url-excluding-ip-and-directory

Comment: Thank you, @eisaacson. It works, but only for "/". I can still view "/blog". The redirection works only for the root directory? By the way, I have another location directive specified for "/blog". Could that be the reason why its not working? I thought the "last" parameter would have prevented Nginx from evaluating other location directives?

Comment: Another problem: Assets (such as images) also failed to load in Coming Soon page.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Yes, having a location block for /blog will override the / block for that directory. Is your /blog block before the / block?

Comment: @HoneyBadger If you are trying to load assets from other directories than /coming-soon, they will be redirected just like everything else. I did a similar thing recently but I just made my '/coming-soon' directory completely independent, having all the assets inside of it.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Did you get this to work?

Comment: this will loop the redirect